# Usage Of Model and @ModelAttribute in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, modelattribute

I am new to Spring MVC and trying to convert a Struts 2 Application to Spring MVC.
Now there are so many options to handle request parameters and setting data to be rendered on.
     Let me explain by following code:

```
    @RequestMapping("/sales"
    public Class SalesController{
          @AutoWired 
          ISaleService saleService;
          ...
               ///getters and setters for service instance.omitted for brevity
          ...
          @RequestMapping("/")
          public String viewRoles(@ModelAttribute SaleBean saleBean,
          Map<String,Object> model){
             List<Sale> sales = getSaleService().getAllSales();
             model.put("sales",sales); //Option 1 to render sales on jsp form

             SaleBean saleBean = new SaleBean();
             saleBean.setSales(sales); //option 2 to render sales on jsp form
             model.put("saleBean",saleBean)   
          } 
    }
```

In above example I have shown two options which both work fine and I can render sales info on JSP.Also I have command name as "saleBean" on my form.

1.Is Model parameter which is usually used to put data on outgoing response so that is can be rendered on JSP really needed when I am using @ModelAttribute as a second parameter?

2.Do I need to explicitly instantiate SaleBean class in Option 2 of my code? Will spring instantiate it if its already null?

3.Do I need to put saleBean into model explicitly?from spring docs it seems @Modelattribute  object is also put  on model implicitly.

Comment: 1 - I don't understand that question; 2 - spring will always instantiate `@ModelAttribute` beans and bind request parameters on them; 3 - `@ModelAttribute` will be automatically included in request attributes

Comment: @PavelHoral 1 - In other words do I always need Model Map if I already have "@ModelAttribute" and as you told it will always be put in response? if so can I use it in my JSP without putting it in Model explicitly? I am wrapping everything that is to be shown on JSP in my SaleBean

Comment: If you don't need other model attributes, you dont need model as a method argument.

Comment: @PavelHoral Ok. so finally, that means if I am wrapping everything to be shown on JSP in my SaleBean then and I am using it as my ModelAttribute then 1) I dont need to use Model ma as another argument and 2) I dont need to put my salebean argument into model explicitly to have it on my JSP. it will be implicitly made available correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.